# DS1307 RTC displaying issue

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip, real-time-clock

I have used PIC18F24k40 series MCU with DS1307. Here is portion of code posted.  DATE_TIME_SET_ADD() function where i am setting time.Display_RTC_Clock() is displaying time. currently it working like this

i am setting value of MIN_SET & SEC_SET =0X40 in decimal . but in Run mode while displaying ,it display hexadecimal value 0X28

```
Temp1= sec & 0x0f;Temp2= sec>> 4;
LEDBuffer_1[0] = DISPTABLE[Temp1];
LEDBuffer_1[1] = DISPTABLE[Temp2];
Temp3 = min & 0x0f;Temp4= min >> 4;
LEDBuffer_1[2] = DISPTABLE[Temp3];
LEDBuffer_1[3] = DISPTABLE[Temp4];
```

If i change below value it will display hexadecimal value after 40. if i set MIN_SET & SEC_SET =0X00 then properly increment. But for MIN_SET & SEC_SET=0X40
min parameter shows 0X40 and sec parameter display for 56 it shows 38

```
Temp1= sec %10;Temp2= sec/10;
LEDBuffer_1[0] = DISPTABLE[Temp1];
LEDBuffer_1[1] = DISPTABLE[Temp2];
Temp3 = min %10;Temp4= min /10;
LEDBuffer_1[2] = DISPTABLE[Temp3];
LEDBuffer_1[3] = DISPTABLE[Temp4];
```

what are changes need to made to display actual value. Somewhere i need to convert bcd to decimal and decimal to Bcd conversion

Comment: Are you setting it to 40 or 0x40?  0x28=40.

Comment: Where did you set `MIN_SET`to `0x40`?